# Using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql to connect to mysql with .net 6 on mac

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I am trying to use Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql to be able to connect to my MySQL database. I am using .NET 6 which removes startup.cs from the project and merges everything into the Program.cs.

The following code is the way I am trying to connect to my database, but it is giving me an error with serverVersion.

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");


var serverVersion = new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 28));

builder.Services.AddDbContext<BirdProjectContext>(
            dbContextOptions => dbContextOptions
                .UseMySQL(connectionString, serverVersion)
                // The following three options help with debugging, but should
                // be changed or removed for production.
                .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information)
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors()
        );
```

The error I get is:

CS1503: Argument 3: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.MySqlServerVersion' to 'System.Action<MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.MySQLDbContextOptionsBuilder>'

If I try to remove the serverversion from the parameters, I get another error:

CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQLDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseMySQL(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder, string, System.Action<MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.MySQLDbContextOptionsBuilder>)' and 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQLDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseMySQL(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder, string, System.Action<MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.MySQLDbContextOptionsBuilder>)'

This project was using SQL and now I am trying to convert it to MySQL.

These are the packages I have installed into the project:

[Nuget Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i9qn.png)

Answer (score 4):

EntityFramework has a way to get dynamically the DB server version, try this way:

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<BirdProjectContext>(
    dbContextOptions => dbContextOptions
        .UseMySQL(connectionString,  ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString))
        // The following three options help with debugging, but should
        // be changed or removed for production.
        .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information)
        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
        .EnableDetailedErrors()
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the **`UseMySQL()` method**, which belongs to **Oracle's provider**, not the Pomelo provider.

For the **Pomelo provider**, use the **`UseMySql()` method (different casing)**.

Samples how to call it, can be found on the main page of our GitHub repository, which uses the correct casing:

```cs
// Replace with your connection string.
var connectionString = "server=localhost;user=root;password=1234;database=ef";

// Replace with your server version and type.
// Use 'MariaDbServerVersion' for MariaDB.
// Alternatively, use 'ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString)'.
// For common usages, see pull request #1233.
var serverVersion = new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 29));

// Replace 'YourDbContext' with the name of your own DbContext derived class.
services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(
    dbContextOptions => dbContextOptions
        .UseMySql(connectionString, serverVersion)
        // The following three options help with debugging, but should
        // be changed or removed for production.
        .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information)
        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
        .EnableDetailedErrors()
);
```

Comment: This helped me with my issue when I migrated from Oracle MySQL provider to Pomelo. My project wasn't building and I didn't notice the casing difference until I read your response. My project now compiles successfuly, thanks a bunch!